# ¿Por qué este código tiene este 'Return' al final?

Tags: python

Soy nuevo en Python, y no entiendo muy bien el motivo del 'return x' del siguiente código (se encuentra en el último `if`):

```
def nombre ():
    letras = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','ñ',
              'o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    while True:
        x = input(":> ").lower()
        verificacion = True
        
        for letra in x:
            if letra not in letras:
                print("Ingrese solo letras")
                verificacion = False
                break
        if verificacion == True:
            return x 
nombre()
```

Comment: return dice al código "dejá de ejecutar la función y devolvé x". Ese valor devuelto se puede, por ejemplo, guardar en una variable. En este caso, cuando el valor es valido,  termina la ejecución de la función y devuelve x. De lo contrario, vuelve a pedir el dato al usuario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piensa en una función como un fragmento de código que puede recibir unos datos de entrada (los parámetros), luego realiza una tarea, como procesar esos datos de entrada y cuando termina genera un resultado que devuelve a quien la llamo, que es el retorno de la función.

**Toda función en Python retorna algo cuando termina su ejecución**, concretamente, toda función retorna una referencia a un solo objeto cuando termina su ejecución.

Si no definimos explícitamente que una función retorne algo concreto, se retorna `None` por defecto:

```
>>> def foo():
        pass
    
>>> salida = foo()
>>> type(salida)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Si queremos que la función retorne algo en concreto se usa la sentencia `return` seguida de lo que queremos que retorne.

```
>>> def suma(a, b):
        resultado = a + b
        return resultado

>>> suma(3, 5)
8
```

Esta función recibe como entrada dos enteros, los suma y retorna el resultado.

Si al `return` le sigue una expresión, se evalúa la expresión y se retorna el resultado de dicha evaluación.

```
>>> def suma(a, b):
        return a + b

>>> suma(3, 5)
8
```

Como toda función retorna algo, ese retorno puedes asignarlo a una variable, usarlo como argumento para otra función o método, etc:

```
>>> def suma(a, b):
        return a + b

>>> res = suma(3, 5)
>>> print(res)
8

>>> lista_sumas = [suma(2, 7)]
>>> lista_sumas.append(suma(3, 4))
>>> print(lista_sumas)
[9, 7]
```

Puedes definir los `return` que quieras en una misma función:

```
def div(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return a / b
```

Una cosa muy importante a tener en cuenta es que, **cuando una sentencia `return` es ejecutada, la ejecución de la función termina inmediatamente en ese punto**. No importa que estés en mitad de un ciclo, en un condicional, etc, cuando el `return` se ejecuta la función termina y retorna lo que indique el `return`.

Por ultimo, podemos hacer que una función "retorne mas de una cosa", por ejemplo:

```
def eco(a, b):
    return a, b
```

en este caso la función simplemente retorna los dos argumentos que recibe sin mas. Y podemos asignar su salida a variables:

```
n, m = eco(3, 7)
print(n)
print(m)
```

y no, no mentí cuando afirme al principio "que toda función retorna siempre un solo objeto", en realidad la función retorna una tupla. `return a, b` es solo azúcar sintáctica para `return (a, b)`, de hecho:

```
>>> type(eco(4, 5))
<class 'tuple'>
>>> retorno = eco(4, 5)
>>> print(retorno)
(4, 5)
>>> type(retorno)
<class 'tuple'>
```

Cuando hacemos `n, m = eco(3, 7)` estamos diciendo que se asigne a `n` el primer item de la tupla y a `m` el segundo, es lo que se conoce como "desestructuración".

---

En tu caso, la función `nombre` lo que hace básicamente es pedir una entrada al usuario, la asigna a la variable `x` y a continuación la valida (comprueba que esa entrada no tenga ningún carácter que no este presente en la lista `letras`). Si entrada del usuario (variable `x`) es válida la función la retorna, si no es valida vuelve a pedir de nuevo al al usuario que ingrese otra cadena, repitiendo el proceso hasta que ingrese algo válido.

El `return` como se ha dicho tiene la función de devolver un valor cuando la función complete su tarea, en este caso retorna la cadena que el usuario a ingresado tras comprobar que es válida. Si se cumple la condición `if verificacion == True:` se ejecuta el `return`, la función termina inmediatamente su ejecución y devuelve la cadena (`x`). Por tanto, como efecto colateral, el `return` termina lo que es en esencia un ciclo infinito (`while True:`).

Por ultimo, la función es inútil si no haces nada con esa cadena que retorna. Si simplemente llamas a la función haciendo `nombre()`, la cadena que retorna no es asignada a nada y no podrás usarla. Puedes por ejemplo asignarla a una variable:

```
nombre_usuario = nombre()
print(f"El nombre que has ingresado es: {nombre_usuario}")
```

---

Dos observaciones al margen:

- Usar `if verificacion == True:`, aunque no sea estrictamente incorrecto, no es la forma apropiada de verificar si una variable es verdadera o no en Python, en su lugar se debe hacer simplemente: `if verificacion:`.
- Como curiosidad, los ciclos `for` de Python pueden tener un clausula opcional `else`, que se ejecuta solo si el ciclo se ha completado (no se ha roto con un `break`). En este caso se puede usar para simplificar el código prescindiendo de la variable auxiliar `verificacion`:

  ```
    while True:
        x = input(":> ").lower()        
        for letra in x:
            if letra not in letras:
                print("Ingrese solo letras")
                break
        else:
            return x
  ```